# Seaborn confusion matrix with latex font

Tags: latex, seaborn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to create a confusion matrix in seaborn with a latex font (Sans Serif). I tried `rc('text', usetex=True)` and `sns.set(rc={'text.usetex': True})` but it did not work. The first method doesn't change anything, the second changes only the font at color bar to latex. I would appreciate any hints.

Reproducible example:

```
from random import randint
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import rc
from seaborn import set
from seaborn import set_style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels):
    rc('text', usetex=True)
    rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{cmbright}')
    set(font_scale=1.2)
    set_style("darkgrid")

    sns.set(rc={'text.usetex': True})

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, normalize='true')
    sns.heatmap(np.round(cm, 2), annot=True, cmap="Blues", vmin=0, vmax=1, xticklabels=labels, yticklabels=labels, ax=ax)

x = [randint(0, 25) for p in range(0, 30)]
y = [randint(0, 25) for p in range(0, 30)]

labels = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8",
          "Category 9", "Category 10", "Category 111", "Category 12 ", "Category 13", "Category 14", "Category 15", "Category 16",
          "Category 17", "Category 18", "Category 19", "Category 20", "Category 21", "Category 22",
          "Category 23", "Category 24", "Category 25", "Category 26"]
plot_confusion_matrix(x, y, labels)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code seems to work:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels):
    sns.set(rc={'text.usetex': True}, font="serif", font_scale=1.2)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, normalize='true')
    sns.heatmap(np.round(cm, 2), annot=True, cmap="Blues", vmin=0, vmax=1, xticklabels=labels, yticklabels=labels, ax=ax)
```